# Tensorflow-Serving :requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client

Tags: python-3.x, http, request, tensorflow-serving, rest

I have served my custom model an object detection API for cellphones basic on a pre-trained model. So, I want to send requests to the service:
http://localhost:8501/v1/models/cellphone:predict
The HTTP\REST API running correctly.

I used Docker and TensorFlow-serving.

For the requests, I used a python script that returns the avg time, here is the python script:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/serving/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py

The only changes were the image and my server model:

```
# The server URL specifies the endpoint of your server running the ResNet
# model with the name "resnet" and using the predict interface.
SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/cellphone:predict'

# The image URL is the location of the image we should send to the server
IMAGE_URL = 'https://assets.kotsovolos.gr/product/199086-b.jpg'
```

and when I run the $ python resnet_client.py I take this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "resnet_client.py", line 73, in <module> main() File `resnet_client.py", line 57, in main response.raise_for_status() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://localhost:8501/v1/models/cellphone:predict`
```

Is there anybody that can help me to send the correct requests?
Thank U in advanced

System information
Linux Ubuntu 16.04
-python 3.5
TensorFlow Serving installed from binary
TensorFlow ModelServer: 2.1.0-rc1
TensorFlow Library: 2.1.0

Comment: Answered in https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1641